# What tool can I use to verify the output from Nmap?

Tags: nmap, operating-systems

With OS detection enabled I noticed that the device fingerprints is running something entirely wrong. Is there another tool that I can use that can verify since something looks odd?

Comment: Please use a search engine with phrases like [os detection tools](https://www.google.com/search?q=os+detection+tools) and you'll find various recommendations. Apart from that all of these tools are based on heuristics which can be either deliberately broken by the target (like servers having other banners configured) or can be broken by firewalls in front of it or similar. So in order to understand what is "entirely wrong" you better understand what the wrong observation is based on and why it might be wrong, instead of using a different tool in the hope it gets better.